# SQL Select Duplicate Result Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm very new to SQL and this is my first attempt at writing a query.

I've managed to pull the data I require with the below, but due to each item having multiple `useddates` my Results show more than one instance for each item. I've tried using MAX unsure if I am doing it right.

Expected result: to only see one entry per item with newest `lastuseddate`.

```
use bosext
SELECT  artno, shorttext, longtext, price,MAX(lastuseddate) as LastUsed
FROM accountitem, accountitemdyn
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM shelfitem  
     WHERE accountitem.ID = shelfitem.itemID)
Group by accountitem.artno,shorttext, longtext, price, lastuseddate
```

[image]

Comment: post all tables with sample data

Comment: Managed to get it to work with the below guidance :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use group by without `lastuseddate`

```
Group by accountitem.artno,shorttext, longtext, price
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` rather than `WHERE EXISTS`, join your two account tables using correct joins and don't include `lastuseddate` in the `GROUP BY` as it is already in an aggregate function.

```
USE bosext
SELECT ai.artno, shorttext, longtext, price, MAX(lastuseddate) AS LastUsed
FROM accountitem ai
INNER JOIN accountitemdyn aid ON = ai.? = aid.?
FULL OUTER JOIN shelfitem s ON ai..ID = s.itemID
Group by ai.artno, shorttext, longtext, price
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not include lastuseddate in group by clause

```
use bosext
SELECT  artno, shorttext, longtext, price,MAX(lastuseddate) as LastUsed
FROM accountitem, accountitemdyn
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM shelfitem  
     WHERE accountitem.ID = shelfitem.itemID)
Group by accountitem.artno,shorttext, longtext, price
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `lastuseddate` from `Group By` clause

Try below method

```
SELECT  artno, shorttext, longtext, price,MAX(lastuseddate) as LastUsed
FROM accountitem, accountitemdyn
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM shelfitem  
     WHERE accountitem.ID = shelfitem.itemID)
Group by accountitem.artno,shorttext, longtext, price
```